# Force using Wi-Fi over Mobile Data as active connection android

Tags: android, tcpclient, android-wifi

I'm trying to build a tcpClient. The case is: I have a mobile Android device and IoT device and I want to connect the mobile device to IoT device's WiFi with no internet connection and send some information using TcpClient. Everything works fine when Android device has only active WiFi network. When the android device has active both Wifi connection(to IoT device) and mobile data at the same time, android ConnectivityManager will return "Mobile" as ActiveNetworkInfo and TCP client will fail to find IoT device(of course because it uses another network socket). Is there a way to force the android device to use WiFi network over mobile data?

If I get `connectivityManager.GetAllNetworks()` it returns 2 active networks, it's just an evidence that Android device is being connected to wifi and mobile data at the same time.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?